# Как правильно экранировать название?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код, который проверяет выбранный radio button

```
  $('input[name=post[post_type_id]]').change(function(){
    var value = $('input[name=post[post_type_id]]:checked').val();
    alert(value);
  });
```

Который выдает ошибку

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=post[post_type_id]]
```

Я так понимаю из за того что название name уже содержит [] как правильно указать?

Comment: Может не совсем понимаю но почему не `$(this)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Тупанул, будет вот так.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("input[name='post[post_type_id]']").change(function(){
    var value = $("input[name='post[post_type_id]']:checked").val();
    alert(value);
  });
  </script>
```